# no overload of 'max' matching 'std::function<const int &(const int &, const int &)>'

Tags: c++, function

This code fails to compile, and gives the error:

```
test.cpp:12:4: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
   func(std::max<int>);
   ^~~~
test.cpp:4:6: note: candidate function not viable: no overload of 'max' matching 'std::function<const int &(const int &, const int &)>' for 1st argument
void func(std::function<const int &(const int &, const int &)> a)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
#include <algorithm>

void func(std::function<const int &(const int &, const int &)> a)
// void func(const int &a(const int &, const int &))       //this one works
{
   std::cout << a(4,5) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   func(std::max<int>);
}
```

I previously used a function pointer with the same argument signature as `std::function` and that worked. What's going on here?

Comment: Typo ? `std::max` needs `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: @RichardCritten That's not the issue here because the code works with the function pointer approach, but I just I just added that library to verify and it didn't fix the error. I think `functional` includes `algorithm`

Comment: One std header *can* include another, but there is never any guarantee it does.

Comment: I've added  `#include <algorithm>` to the code since it still breaks with it here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2184922d3c16564

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont. Sure, but the lack of `#include<algorithm>` isn't the issue here because that code did compile with the function pointer approach.

Comment: @OP FWIW, instead of arguing, just add it.  It removes a potential problem point and you want as few of those as possible for a good reaction to your question.

Comment: @NathanOliver Got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A std function is not a function pointer.

The name of a template function experiences overload resolution when called or when cast to a function pointer.  It does not experience overload resolution when passed to a std function.

`std::max<int>` could refer to more than one function; ones taking an initializer list or two arguments that are `int`s, and each of those have overloads that take comparators or not.

With overload resolution, all but one of these are discarded.  Without, the result is ambiguous.

```
int x00 = std::max<int>( std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3,4} )
int x01 = std::max<int>( 2, 4 );
int x10 = std::max<int>( std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3,4}, [](int a, int b){ return b>a; } )
int x11 = std::max<int>( 2, 4, [](int a, int b){ return b>a; } );
```

by saying `std::max<int>` you are saying one of those 4 are being used.

And yes, there is only one of them that work with `std::function`, but the C++ language code that calls the `std::function` doesn't know this, so it says the result is ambiguous.  (note that two of the above are an infinite set of possible signatures).

Meanwhile,

```
int const&(*ptr)(int const&,int const&) = std::max<int>;
```

here, we are doing overload resolution.  We pick the `std::max<int>` that takes two `int`s.

```
std::function<int const&(int const&, int const&)> f = std::max<int>;
```

here we don't do overload resolution on `std::max`.

An easy fix for this is:

```
std::function<int const&(int const&, int const&)> f =
  [](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto)
  { return std::max<int>(decltype(args)(args)...); };
```

which I sometimes write as a macro

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept( __VA_ARGS__ )) \
  -> decltype( __VA_ARGS__ ) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }
#define CALL(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) )
```

giving us:

```
std::function<int const&(int const&, int const&)> f = CALL(std::max<int>);
```

here I *delay* overload resolution until after we invoke the callable object we pass `f`.  At that point the types are known, so everything works.

Comment: What are you doing with `decltype(args)(args)...`? Did you mean `std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...`?

Comment: @NathanOliver No, I meant to type less characters and do the exact same thing.  I am casting each `arg` to the type it was declared as.  I'm not conditionally moving (aka `std::forward`ing).  In this case the result is identical (as `args`s are forwarding references) but shorter, in other contexts it is different.

Comment: Haven't used `decltype` before, but if you're casting something, don't you typically need a pair of parenthesis around the type you're casting to? So in this case, should it be `std::max<int>((decltype(args))(args)...)`?